# Why does it seem that only hard coded values work in Filtered table expressions in DAX?

Tags: dynamic, powerbi, dax, var, tablefilter

I have a measure [D Cohort Start Date Key] which is selected by a filter and derived from a static table of date key values.

I created a table In PBI:

```
Dynamic List of IDs at Time T = 
var Pdate = CONVERT([D Cohort Start Date Key], DOUBLE)
--assume [D Cohort Start Date Key] evaluates to 20200331
var FilteredTable = FILTER('CustTable', 'CustTable'[DimBusinessDateKey] = Pdate)
RETURN 
SELECTCOLUMNS(FilteredTable,"CustID",[CustID])
```

However this returns a table with no values when values are expected. I have hard-coded a datekey value of 20200331 instead of Pdate in the formula and it returns the values expected. Why is this? I want to use the DateKey variable (and perhaps other variables and measures selected by the user via filtres) In the filteredTable Variable to make this dynamic.

Comment: if you are trying to create a table in your data model that you expect to respond to user selections, than you are on a wrong track because it's not possible (and not necessary)

Comment: For cohort analysis it is very necessary for a user to analyze groups of records based on a criteria through time. This comment isn't useful or helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the result of `Pdate`. In fact, if you calculate in the exact filter and row context as `FilteredTable`, I am sure you will have your answer.

Therefore, you need to debug the variable Pdate. 
You have two options:

A) Power BI
Create a standalone measure,

```
Debug:=CONVERT([D Cohort Start Date Key], DOUBLE)
```

and evaluate it in the same filter and row context as `FilteredTable` is giving you problems. This might be a non trivial task, therefore, see option B)

B) DAX Studio
If you have not been able to evaluate `Debug` in the same filter context as `FilteredTable`, use DAX Studio.

```
EVALUATE 
SELECTCOLUMNS('CustTable', "FilteredValue", 'CustTable'[DimBusinessDateKey], "Pdate", CONVERT([D Cohort Start Date Key], DOUBLE))
```

This expression generates the table on which the filter of `FilteredTable` is applied. At this point it will be clear the value of Pdate and you will have the answer to your problem.

Comment: So I did a card with this new debug measure and it is displaying 20,200,331.00.I have attempted to apply a FORMAT in the FilterTable thusly: FORMAT(CONVERT([D Cohort Start Date Key], DOUBLE),"0") and I got an error: DAX comparison operations do not support comparing values of type Number with values of type Text. Consider using the VALUE or FORMAT function to convert one of the values

Comment: If I use the measure [D Cohort Start Date Key] by itself, then the card is correct at 20200331 but the data still doesn't show up...

Comment: The card in this scenario is meaningless because it is not the same row context as when you calculate FilteredTable. Instead, create a Table visualization with 2 columns: 'CustTable'[Primary Key], CustTable'[DimBusinessDateKey] and Pdate measure. What is the result?

Comment: I can create this table and I see the value of whatever I saw in the card repeated for every row of CustTable[PrimaryKey] and CustTable[DimBusinessDate]. that is, in this case 20200331.

Comment: Export it into Excel and check if the values are equal.

Comment: CustTable[DimBusinessDateKey] = 20200331 and [D Cohort Start Date Key] = 20200331. Excel says they are equal.

Comment: I have done this and confirmed the values are equal.